# Ember.ArrayController.create() not returning unique instances

Tags: ember.js

I'm sure I must be missing something obvious here: I'm creating 3 objects each with a property that is set to an ArrayController. As I add each new object the ArrayController instance shares the content from the previous controller instead of being a unique instance:

http://jsfiddle.net/w6DKR/3/

In my example, the only way I can fix this is to do `this.set('content', []);` in the ArrayController init method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Initialization (and a common mistake!)**

One of the most common mistakes for beginners to Ember is to think they’re passing properties to an instance instead of a prototype. For example:

```
var Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  chromosomes: ["x"] // CAREFUL !!!!!
});

var joe = Person.create();
joe.get("chromosomes").push("y");

var jane = Person.create();
jane.get("chromosomes").push("x");

// Joe and Jane are all mixed up?!?!?!?!
console.log( joe.get("chromosomes") );  // x, y, x
console.log( jane.get("chromosomes") ); // x, y, x
```

Why did this chromosomal mutation happen? The problem started when we added an array to our prototype when defining the Person class. This array was then shared with each object instantiated from Person.

How should we have handled this?

```
var Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  chromosomes: null,
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.chromosomes = ["x"]; // everyone gets at least one X chromosome
  }
});

var joe = Person.create();
joe.get("chromosomes").push("y");  // men also get a Y chromosome

var jane = Person.create();
jane.get("chromosomes").push("x"); // women get another X chromosome

// Hurray - everyone gets their own chromosomes!
console.log( joe.get("chromosomes") );  // x, y
console.log( jane.get("chromosomes") ); // x, x
```

When declaring objects or arrays in your classes, you’ll typically want to initialize them along with each instance in the init() function. In this way, each of your objects will receive its own unique instances of objects and arrays. Also remember to call this._super() from within init() so that init() will be called all the way up the prototype chain.

Of course, there’s nothing wrong with keeping objects or arrays directly in your prototypes if they are meant to remain constant across instances. In fact, one common pattern is to keep a default setting in the prototype that’s then duplicated for each instance in init(). These kinds of patterns are easy to implement once you realize how objects are created and initialized.

Copied from article : http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you usually don't want to be setting `content: []` inside an `.extend({...})` block as each instance will share that same array. AFAIK this is an acceptable, perhaps even common, pattern in Ember.js:

```
App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: null,
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('content', []);
    },
    // ...
});
```